# PHPMailer sends duplicates in a loop

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have this problem like some people with PHPMailer, and I cannot find any solutions on the internet. The problem is that PHPMailer sends duplicates (sometimes more than two) if I set it in a loop (while, foreach). I've checked the loop is just fine, but it keeps sending duplicates.

Here is the code after I made it looks simpler.

```
<?
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pm_mailmembers` WHERE `mm_interval`='2' AND   mm_blocked = 0") or die(mysql_error());
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SingleTo = true;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = "Fiscanet Nieuws";
$sendContent = "<p>This is test mail</p>";
$r_receivers = array("John"=>"john@mail.com","Mary"=>"mary@mail.com","Rob"=>"rob@mail.com");
foreach($r_receivers as $name=>$email){
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@yoursite.com', "Yoursite");
    $mail->MsgHTML($sendContent);
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
    if($mail->Send())
        echo "Sent to: ".$email."<br/>";
    else
        echo "Not sent to: ".$email.", reason: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."<br/>";
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
}
?>
```

I think I need to reset mail->addaddress inside the loop, but mail->clearaddresses doesn't help. And all 3 emails always receives the same emails. So all receives 2 or 3 mails.

Could anyone help me out here?? Thanks.
ayok

---

The problem get even wierder... I've tried to change the code to just a simple mail(), and it keep sending duplicates. What could be the cause? Is it a server configuration problem??

I did this in the subdomain of mysite.com, say sub.mysite.com. Mysite.com and sub.mysite.com are in different servers. Could it be the cause?

Thanks,
ayok

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the code you posted. I think  there is no problem with the code.

**I think when ever you refresh your page the mail is fired.**

So Please **keep the mail code in condition** and then check how many mails you get.
I hope this answer might help you.

Comment: Do you mean that you don't received duplicates mails? The page was made for cron job so I need it to execute the script when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Yes i did not get any duplicate mails.I have checked it thrice.

Comment: But how come do I receive duplicates? Is the refresh the problem? Would you explain what you mean by "keep the mail code in condition"? Thanx

Comment: I suggest you to make a test file and run this code once and check how many mails your getting.With no relating to corn job or any thing else just the above mail code.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I've set a time on the content. The duplicates are sent 6 minutes after the first. 
I've also set an order number, and all the duplicates has same number.

```
<?php
require("PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SingleTo = true;
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$mail->Subject = "Fiscanet Nieuws";
$r_receivers = array("John"=>"john@mail.com","Mary"=>"mary@mail.com","Rob"=>"rob@mail.com");
    $i = 1;
foreach($r_receivers as $name=>$email){
    $mail->SetFrom('no-reply@yoursite.com', "Yoursite");
    $mail->MsgHTML($sendContent);
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
        $sendContent = "<p>This is test mail number ".$i." sent at ".date('H:i:s')."</p>";
    if($mail->Send())
        echo "Sent to: ".$email."<br/>";
    else
        echo "Not sent to: ".$email.", reason: ".$mail->ErrorInfo."<br/>";
    $mail->ClearAddresses();
            $i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
```